# Multiple validators for one field. JSF

Tags: validation, jsp, jsf

Can you apply multiple validators for one field. i.e:

```
     <ice:inputText id="tawjihiAvg" maxlength="5" partialSubmit="true"
                                            style="left: 0px; top: 144px; position: absolute; width: 144px" title="#{msg.Tawjihi_Average}"
                                            value="#{SessionBean1.tawjihiAvg}" valueChangeListener="#{Application.tawjihiAvg_processValueChange}">
                                            <f:validator validatorId="AverageValidator"/>
                                            <f:validator validatorId="required"/>
  </ice:inputText>
```

Ofcourse I registered both validators in faces-config.xml file. Is that allowed ???

Thanks,

Comment: Well, why don't you try it and see it by yourself? Just input some data invalid for each validator and you will se...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you have had a problem with it, it lies somewhere else.